# Необходимо как-то хранить и различать функции

Tags: c++, разработка-игр

Пишу на С++ настольную игру. Есть множество карт и почти у каждой из них есть какая-то уникальная способность. Допустим, у каждой карты есть свой id, и по этому id нужно найти именно ту способность, которую нужно. И тут я становлюсь в тупик, ибо не могу додуматься, как более грамотно это реализовать. Помогите, чем сможете.

Comment: В простейшем случае заведите функцию, которая принимает `id` и с помощью оператора `switch case` вызывает нужную функцию. А если функции принимают и возвращают одинаковые значения, то можно создать словарь, который хранит по `id` указатель на нужную функцию.

Comment: Карта может быть классом, карта с особой способностью - наследником. В наследнике переопределить функцию способности.

Comment: Вам нужно виртуальное наследование.

Comment: какие типы эффектов и уникальных способностей у вас есть в игре?